# How to query Django model using filter

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am query Django model using below query :

```
for i in models.short_url.objects.filter(created_at__month=m,url_hash='DCmuih'):
    count = i.click_info_set.count()
```

There is one way to get the count but without the month filter

```
print models.short_url.objects.get(url_hash='DCmuih').click_info_set.count()
```

But How do i use same query but without for loop...Can someone help me please.

Comment: What about [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses)?`models.short_url.objects.filter(created_at__month=m,url_hash='DCmuih').annotate( c = Count( 'click_info' ) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a bit hard to simply guess by the queryset alone, but this should roughly do it:

```
from django.db.models import Count

queryset = models.short_url.objects.filter(
    created_at__month=m,
    url_hash='DCmuih',
).annotate(click_info_count=Count('click_info__id'))

for short_url in queryset:
    print short_url, short_url.click_info_count
```

Comment: you should change `Count('id')` by `Count('click_info__id')`

Comment: It is not giving count instead it is simply returning the object based on query....

Comment: You will get ```click_info_count``` attribute for each object returned.

Comment: @danihp: Haha, thanks. It was fixed before you posted the comment actually :)

Comment: @user2217267: see the example :)